# Is there a less painful way to call C# from JavaScript using CefSharp?

Tags: .net, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp as an UI for my .Net desktop application, but this part is giving me some headache, for example with the function:

### This is what I **expected** to do:

```
public Sales ProcessSale(Sales sale) {
    sale.Shift = terminal.CurrentShift;
    sale.SalesPerson = terminal.CurrentUser;

    var errors = sale.ValidateInput();

    if (errors.Count > 0) {
        throw new BusinessValidationException(errors);
    }

    terminal.CreateIdentity(sale);
    worker.FireAndForget(() => {
        SafeStorage.Put(sale);
    });
    return sale;
}
```

and then on the JS Side:

```
try {
    let processedSale = await window['sales'].ProcessSale(this.saleModel);
    // ... call print receipt and carry on
} catch(err) {
    this.modalsService.alert(err.Message);
}
```

Nice and clean;

However, it doesn't work. CefSharp passes object parameters as ExpandoObjects and the error thrown in javascript is a full stacktrace print of the C# exception, both treatments are horrible to work with.

### This is what works and I **HATE** having to do:

```
public string ProcessSale(string sale) {
    try {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            ProcessSale(
                JsonConvert.DerializeObject<Sales>(sale)
            )
        );
    } catch(Exception x) {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
    }
}

public Sales ProcessSale(Sales sale) {
    sale.Shift = terminal.CurrentShift;
    sale.SalesPerson = terminal.CurrentUser;

    var errors = sale.ValidateInput();

    if (errors.Count > 0) {
        throw new BusinessValidationException(errors);
    }

    terminal.CreateIdentity(sale);
    worker.FireAndForget(() => {
        SafeStorage.Put(sale);
    });
    return sale;
}
```

and then:

```
async otherwiseUnnecessaryProcessSaleWrapper(saleModel) {
    const modelJson = JSON.stringify(saleModel);
    const retvJson = await window['sales'].ProcessSale(modelJson);
    const retv = JSON.parse(retvJson);
    if(retv.ClassName || retv.StackTrace) {
        throw retv;
    } else {
        return retv;
    }
}
. . .
// and only then:
try {
    let processedSale = await otherwiseUnnecessaryProcessSaleWrapper(this.saleModel);
    // ... call print receipt and carry on
} catch(err) {
    this.modalsService.alert(err.Message);
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this MASSIVE unnecessary verbosity, create a custom javascript interop handler or something, I appreciate in advance.

Comment: How did you register your object? Binding to a custom model is supported. Pay attention to the last param http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IJavascriptObjectRepository_Register.htm